# Best way to index post tags in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I have a collection `posts` like bellow :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad249121c76fb096c0081e6"),
    "slug" : "5ad2491261324",
    "title" : "title",
    "content" : "content here",
    "tags" : [ 
        "tag1", 
        "tag2"
    ],
    "status" : 1,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-12T07:23:07.000Z"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5ad249111c76fb096c007dfd"),
    "url_id" : ObjectId("5ad249121c76fb096c0081e7"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-14T18:31:46.000Z"),
    "images" : [ 
        {
            "extension" : "jpg",
            "path" : "/medias/tests/4.jpg",
            "thumbnail" : "/medias/tests/4-th.jpg",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-14T18:31:46.000Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-14T18:31:46.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ad249121c76fb096c0081e8")
        }
    ]
}
```

In this collection i have 100m record that i need to find posts by tags.

So how can i index it in correct way to get result's in minimum time?

Comment: Add `text` index for `tags` since that's whole purpose of it. We can then efficiently search posts based on tags.

Comment: @RahulRaj Thanks for solution.